# g++ precompiled header not detected in same directory

Tags: c++, linux, g++, clang, precompiled-headers

`peglib.hpp` is a header-only library used to generate parsers  with peg syntax. It takes 34 seconds to compile `main.cpp` which includes said header, which is why im trying to precompile `peglib.hpp`

**Command used to precompile header:**
`g++ peglib.hpp`

**Compile main.cpp:**
`g++ -H main.cpp -o main`

However, compilation time does not change. It is noted that `peglib.hpp` and `peglib.hpp.gch` are in the same directory. No ! or x; precompiled header isn't even detected with -H option.

Some info:
`peglib.hpp` requires c++17.
`main.cpp` includes the header but does not use it, only returns 0 from main.
Im using Termux with clang version 17.0.6 on android 9 arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed an ubuntu distro and it worked fine, looks like its a Termux problem